# Upgrading Godot project

Tags: godot-3

Can I open a game that I made in Godot 3.1 in a later version (3.2 and higher) and get output from it with that higher version?

Comment: What happens when you make a copy of your project and try this? Does something go wrong?

Comment: Did you have a reason to not upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can upgrade your project from 3.0 up to whatever 3.x, and it should work - in most cases.

The advice is make sure you have a backup before doing so. *If you are working with version control, this is not an issue.* The reason why a backup is advised is because downgrading your project is not guaranteed... Mainly because a project for a newer version might be using features not available in older versions.

The incompatibilities you might find while upgrading are mostly behavior changes, but there were some removed features (although there were kept at a minimum and were mostly rarely used features). *This is why I said "in most cases" earlier*.

The bigger incompatibilities within the 3.x versions are for the version 3.2.2 that changed the Android plugin system (so if you rely on old Android plugins that weren't upgraded for the new system you will be in trouble). And also for 3.2.3 that changed the C# project format (you should be able to regenerate the project file if necessary).

Godot is adhering to semantic versioning to a healthy degree. So, as you would expect, a change in the major version version number signifies that the development team took the liberty to break compatibility. In fact, upgrading from 3.x to 4.x is not safe. There is an upgrade system (Godot 4.x will ask you if you want to upgrade a Godot 3.x project the first time you try to open it), it is not perfect, and you will have to spend time making sure your project works and works correctly in Godot 4.x. Furthermore, if you need to go back to Godot 3.x you are on your own (so, again, make sure to have a backup).

---

**Addendum** To upgrade a project to a new version of Godot, you:

- Download the new version of Godot
- Open the new version of Godot
- Open the project in the new version of Godot (if it is a major version, you might have to scan the project folder for Godot to detect it)
- If Godot needs to modify the project to be able to open it, it will ask you if you want to proceed before doing any changes.

That's it.

Comment: I want to bring ads in a game I made in Godot 3.1.
But I don't know how to do it in Godot 3.1.
That's why I decided to upgrade the version of my project.
Is there a resource for teaching this? Is there Admob ads plugin in Godot 3.1?

Comment: @NinaMonti I'm not aware of Admob for Godot 3.1, I'll try to find it. And I'll be answering your other question shortly.

Comment: @NinaMonti If this or any answer has solved your question please consider voting it up &/or accepting it ([more info on that here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)) by clicking the up triangle &/or check-mark respectively. While not mandatory, it indicates to the wider community that you've found a helpful solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.